# v8 extension for node.js - cannot set FunctionTemplate to target

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, embedded-v8

I'm just starting out with writing a binding to a C library (link-grammar, to be precise) via a v8 extension (following instructions on [Node.JS docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/addons.html) and [v8 API docs](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html)).

My problem is that I am getting the following build error:

```
/usr/include/v8.h: In constructor âv8::Handle<T>::Handle(v8::Handle<S>) [with S = v8::FunctionTemplate, T = v8::Value]â:
node.cc:85:68:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/v8.h:195:5: error: cannot convert âv8::FunctionTemplate*â to âv8::Value* volatileâ in assignment
```

...when trying to build the following code:

```
#include <v8.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "link-includes.h"

using namespace v8;

Dictionary dict;
Parse_Options opts;

static Handle<Value> v8parse(const Arguments& args)
{
    /* snip */
}

extern "C" void init (Handle<Object> target)
{
    HandleScope scope;
    target->Set(String::New("parse"), FunctionTemplate::New(v8parse));

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    opts = parse_options_create();
    dict = dictionary_create_lang("en");
}
```

I feel as if I've followed the instructions on the above links, and followed the pattern of the examples they link to, however I get the aforementioned error. Not the sharpest C++ coder out there, so it's very possible the error is staring me in the face. Alas, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Set` method expects a `Handle<Value>`, but you are passing a FunctionTemplate, which can't convert itself automatically. You need to be use GetFunction on the template to get a value handle for it.

```
target->Set(String::New("parse"), FunctionTemplate::New(v8parse)->GetFunction());
```

However, there is a macro for this, so I would recommend doing this:

```
NODE_SET_METHOD(target, "parse", v8parse);
```

I found this blog post/sample code useful when I was playing with this stuff.
https://www.cloudkick.com/blog/2010/aug/23/writing-nodejs-native-extensions/

I'm not 100% sure since it isn't mentioned in the nodejs docs you posted, but I think you'll also need an `extern "C" { NODE_MODULE(yourmodulefilename, init); }` at the bottom of your file to let node know that this is a module for loading.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! Using that macro now, since it seems a little more self-documenting. Still got some fumbling through C++ builds to go, but that gets me past this problem and onto another :p

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to call GetFunction() on your function template. I've only dabbled with c++ extensions to node, but seems like most of the code examples I've seen look something like this:

```
static Persistent<FunctionTemplate> s_ct;

static void Init(Handle<Object> target)
{
  HandleScope scope;

  Local<FunctionTemplate> t = FunctionTemplate::New(New);

  s_ct = Persistent<FunctionTemplate>::New(t);
  s_ct->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
  s_ct->SetClassName(String::NewSymbol("MyClass"));

  NODE_SET_PROTOTYPE_METHOD(s_ct, "someMethod", MyClass::SomeMethod);

  target->Set(String::NewSymbol("MyClass"),
              s_ct->GetFunction());
}
```

A node extension for link-grammar will be cool :)

Comment: Yeah, was kind of surprised nobody had tried making a `node-link-grammar` binding before. Will end up on github... eventually.